# Configuring Systems environment with Java to invoke JNI calls

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, environment-variables

I have written some JNI code that works just fine. I call an API out of Java which needs some environment variables set. Currently, I am working on Windows XP SP3.

I need to set a variable (Example: FOO=bar) in the user space and need to add some paths to the systems path. I need to that because I use third party DLLs in my C code which need these environment settings.

Now I am a bit stuck and don't know how to set these variables. I tried a batch file starting the Java programm, but that didn't work because I only changes the environment for that process. JNI seems to get its own process and there for not the settings I just changed.

So, does any of you have an idea how I could handle that?

Thanks for the help and regards from Germany

Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What sort of batch script are you using?  Normally, variables
set in a process propagate down to all processes created from
that process: if I do

```
set toto=abc
```

in a console window, I find this environment variable in all
programs started from that window.

Comment: Yea, I am using set... So if I start the Java program from that Batch it will work? Current I am invoking the batch from Java...

Comment: It should.  We use it regularly, with no problem.

Comment: Sorry made some mistakse again... Now its fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

JNI does not get its own process - you're doing something wrong in the batch file.

You can set the environment in C code though, using the `SetEnvironmentVariable` API call.